# Hibernate.getCurrentSession() in Multi Threaded Environment

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, swing, hibernate

I need to understand best case to use *Hibernate.getCurrentSession()*?

What I understood is that it is harmful in Multi thread environment like WebApplication(Spring MVC) because Thread which is handling Hibernate.getCurrentSession() transaction will be used by (*Shared*) multiple request (Threads) in web application before anyone commits that Transaction.

```
     Req1 ->
     Req2 ->    WebApp(Spring MVC) |  <-- (Hibernate Current Session Thread)
     Req3 ->
```

The best case for usage of Hibernate.getCurrentSession() is stand alone application (Swing/Desktop) which we call Single Thread application. In this case single thread is in action, hence there is no issue of sharing the transaction.

```
     Event/Action ->    Desktop(Swing) |  <-- (Hibernate Current Session Thread)
```

Could anyone please correct me if I am wrong in my understanding because of my limited exposure to that getCurrentSession() method?

Sharing others experience would be value added for me.

*This is not Duplicate Question*

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. The thread won't be available for others until the request finished processing.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. So other threads will be blocked or will get Exception when they tried to get current session from hibernate?

Comment: No they won't they will get their own thread bound session.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you please write an elaborate explanation for what you have added in the comment as an answer. It will help a lot of ppl clear their understanding.

Comment: "This is not Duplicate Question" Well, that's pretty much a useless affirmation.

Comment: @m0skit0 Do you know answer or know question which is similar like this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, `EntityManager` and `HibernateSession` are not thread safe, but in the context of spring mvc, you usually follow the session-per-request or transaction-per-request pattern which essentially means that your entity manager is bound to a single thread.